# iPhone Memory Leak from AudioToolbox when using MPMoviePlayerViewController iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, video, memory-leaks

I'm using the following code (inside a view controller in a tab bar application) to play video loaded from the main bundle after a user selects a table row.

```
- (void)loadMoviePlayer:(NSString*)moviePath
{
    NSURL* fileURL    =   [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController* player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [fileURL release];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
    [player release];
}
```

The app builds and runs without any obvious problems in the simulator (I haven't tested on a device yet) but when I run it through Instruments a memory leak occurs during video playback.
Instruments highlights the AudioToolbox as the 'Responsible Library' and `SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(_CFString const*, _CFString const*, long&)`
and

```
APComponent::CreateDispatchTable(AudioComponentPluginInterface*, unsigned long)
```

as the 'Responsible Frame(s)'.

Any light you can shed on this would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: I have since tested this code on an actual device (3GS) and have seen no leaks reported. I guess this is an issue with the simulator.

Comment: I've also had a few leaks that only occur on the simulator using AV frameworks! That's probably it

Comment: The problem isn't the "simulator" itself, but rather the AVFoundation framework compiled for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem isn't the "simulator" itself, but rather the AVFoundation
>   framework compiled for Mac OS X. – Alex Nichol Aug 17 '11 at 23:53

I'm setting this comment by Alex as the accepted answer. K

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own custom control for the movie player for iPhone and iPad also, where you can create custom volume management and so many things can manage.

Following method to start moview player. for manage the mov

```
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL andViewController:(UIViewController*)vCtr
{
    self.mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    // we have movie from file - Alizee :)
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

    // we don't need standard controlls as we have built our own
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

    // aspect fit to screen  mode
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];

    // full screen mode
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    // to start movie player
    [vCtr presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mPlayer];

    // now we will add our own view over video player
    self.vCtr.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height-20);

    [self.mPlayer.view addSubview:self.vCtr.view];
}

- (void)stopTapped:(id)sender{
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer stop];
}

-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self.mPlayer dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
    [self.vCtr.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's useful information but it doesn't answer the original question about memory leakage.