# Memory leak using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, ios4, avaudioplayer

I'm analyzing leaks in my Objective-C++ code using the instrumentation, and I'm getting this:

```
Leaked Object   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 32 Bytes,0x8135bc0   32 Bytes    AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)
__NSCFDictionary,0x8135be0  48 Bytes    AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)
Malloc 32 Bytes,0x8135c10   32 Bytes    AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)
Malloc 32 Bytes,0x8135c30   32 Bytes    AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)
Malloc 48 Bytes,0x8135c50   48 Bytes    AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)
__NSCFDictionary,0x813a820  48 Bytes    AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)
__NSCFArray,0x813a850   32 Bytes    AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)
__NSCFDictionary,0x813a870  48 Bytes    AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)
Malloc 32 Bytes,0x813a8a0   32 Bytes    AudioToolbox    SimAggregateDevice::SimAggregateDevice(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, long&)
Malloc 32 Bytes,0x813a8d0   32 Bytes    AudioToolbox    CreateDictionaryForDevice(unsigned long)
```

I assume this is related to the code I wrote to play a sound when my application starts. I do it this way: this method is invoked in applicationDidFinishLaunching::

```
- (void)playJingle {
    // This is a detached thread so I need a new pool.
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // This audio player will be released in  audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying.
    NSString *newAudioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jingle" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer *av = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile] error:NULL];
    [av setDelegate:self];
    [av play];

    // Release.
    [pool release];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer*)av successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    // Release the AVAudioPlayer.
    [av release];
}
```

in a background thread (invoked with performSelectorInBackground:withObject:). Am I missing something? Why do I have those leaks?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried running the application on the device?  AVAudioPlayer is prone to false positives with memory leak detection on the simulator...

[Here's a very similar question with a similar looking leak report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080922/iphone-memory-leak-from-audiotoolbox-when-using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-ios-4)

Comment: Unfortunately I rarely can test on the real device, so I just wanted to know if there is any mistake in the way I used and freed the object. Indeed I've seen around someone else reporting something somehow similar, but not identical. So, should I expect to get leaks in the simulator that may disappear on the real device? Or this is an exception? Thanks!

Comment: You'll rarely see leaks that show in the simulator but not a physical device, but with some libraries it can happen.  Your usage of AVAudioPlayer looks fine to me!

Answer (score -1):

This can't work, you assign the `AVPlayer` to a local variable:

```
AVAudioPlayer *av = ...
```

and not to an instance variable.

```
-(void>) playJinlge{
    ...
    self.av = .....
}

-(void) didfinish ... {
   [self.av release];
   self.av=nil;
}
```

Comment: Why should I need to do that? A pointer to AVAudioPlayer is provided by the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying.